# Update Google Sheet Cell in For Loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a for loop that reads information from a google sheet by row, logs into a switch based on the info provided and configures a port. I want to add to it that every time it goes through the data in the row to write CONFIGURED in the Notes cell in the same row. Here is an example of what the spreadsheet looks like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rg5Mhic8omQdlphIZNDPgbVBdLMj6WzPdmgz5XsJKb4/edit?usp=sharing

I am using gspreads and when I do this it only updates CONFIGURED in the first matched cell.

```
    sheet = file.open("SPREADSHEET")
    sheet = sheet.sheet1 

    mydata = sheet.get_all_records()

    datetoday = time.strftime('%m-%d-%y', localtime)

    for row in mydata:
        if row["Date"] == datetoday: 
            #
            #all the netmiko stuff to configure the port goes here
            #
            coordinates = sheet.find(datetoday)
            cell_info=("F"+str(coordinates.row))
            sheet.update(cell_info,"TEST")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the following sheet in a Google Spreadsheet at the 1st tab.

  | Asset ID | Date | Name | IP | Port | Notes |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1234 | 05/16/23 | SWITCH01 | 1.1.1.1 | ge1/1/1 |  |
  | 3456 | 05/16/23 | SWITCH01 | 1.1.1.1 | ge1/1/2 |  |
- When the value of `datetoday` is `05/16/23`, you want to put a value of `CONFIGURED` to the same row of column "F" (Column "Notes").

#### Modification points:

- In your Spreadsheet, the format of the date is `05/16/23`. But, your script uses `%m-%d-%y`. In this case, it should be `%m/%d/%y`.
- Your Spreadsheet has a header row. It is required to consider this.
- In your script, `update` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. And, Sheets API is used several times.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
localtime = time.localtime() # This is a sample value. Please use this for your actual situation/
value = "CONFIGURED" # This is from your question.

sheet = file.open("SPREADSHEET")
sheet = sheet.sheet1
mydata = sheet.get_all_records()
datetoday = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y", localtime)
body = [{"range": "F" + str(i + 2), "values": [[value]]} for i, row in enumerate(mydata) if row["Date"] == datetoday]
if body != []:
    sheet.batch_update(body, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

When this script is run, "CONFIGURED" is put into column "F" of the searched value of `datetoday`.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.1/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.batch_update)

Comment: Yes the API is already set and my script already works without issues, the only thing I want to add is the CONFIGURED part to it. I am using a loop since for each IP on the list I am having the script log into a switch and execute a set of commands, at the point when it finishes with the commands I need it to input the value CONFIGURED. If the command execution fails I don't want it to input any value, so that is why I was placing the value update in the same loop as the rest of my config. If I do it this way it will add CONFIGURED to every lane that matches todays date.

Comment: @Иван Thank you for replying. From `Yes the API is already set and my script already works without issues,`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `the only thing I want to add is the CONFIGURED part to it`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?